# Error T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Tags: php, html

Estoy intentando hacer que aparezca una imagen en cada fila de la tabla, justo al lado del nombre del directorio. Hasta ahora he conseguido que aparezca la misma imagen (gracias a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/332694/c%C3%B3mo-poner-una-imagen-a-un-directorio/332708#332708)), haciendo que quede así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esta parte de código: (véase el resto del código en la pregunta enlazada anterior)

```
echo("
        <tr class='$class'>
            <td><img src='./.LGYTL_LOGO.png'><a href='./$namehref' class='imagen_directorio'>$name</a></td>
            <td><a href='./$namehref'>$extn</a></td>
            <td sorttable_customkey='$sizekey'><a href='./$namehref'>$size</a></td>
            <td sorttable_customkey='$timekey'><a href='./$namehref'>$modtime</a></td>
        </tr>");
```

Pero lo que queremos conseguir es que cada directorio tenga una imagen distinta. Por ejemplo:

> Prueba 1 - gato.jpg
>
> Prueba 2 - perro.jpg
>
> Prueba 3 - conejo.jpg

Intentando esto mismo, me dieron la opción de hacerlo como con una lista por nombres, usando este código:

```
$url_imagen = '';

switch($nombre_directorio) {

case 'perro'
$url_imagen = 'perro.jpg'
break;

case 'gato'
$url_imagen = 'gato.jpg'
break;

case 'conejo'
$url_imagen = 'conejo.jpg'
break;

}
```

Quedando como resultado este código:

```
$url_imagen = '';

                switch($nombre_directorio) {

                case 'perro': $url_imagen='perro.jpg'; break;

                case "gato": $url_imagen='gato.jpg'; break;

                case 'conejo': $url_imagen='conejo.jpg'; break;

        }

    // Output
     echo("
        <tr class='$class'>
            <td><img src="' .$url_imagen. '">'<a href='./$namehref' class='imagen_directorio'>$name</a></td>
            <td><a href='./$namehref'>$extn</a></td>
            <td sorttable_customkey='$sizekey'><a href='./$namehref'>$size</a></td>
            <td sorttable_customkey='$timekey'><a href='./$namehref'>$modtime</a></td>
        </tr>");
```

Pero me da el siguiente error en el navegador:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' .$url_imagen. ''
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /var/www/html/docext/prueba/.index.php
>   on line 131

En la línea 131 está:

```
<td>'<img src="' .$url_imagen. '">'<a href='./$namehref' class='imagen_directorio'>$name</a></td>
```

Busqué sobre el error y decía que era por un error de concatenación, porque faltaba algún punto, pero no veo que me falte nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que te da lo tienes justo en la linea de la imagen lo tienes asi:

```php
<td><img src="' .$url_imagen. '">'<a href='./$namehref' class='imagen_directorio'>$name</a></td>
```

Cuando debería tenerlo de la siguiente manera:

```php
<td><img src='" .$url_imagen. "'><a href='./$namehref' class='imagen_directorio'>$name</a></td>
```

El problema lo tienes en las comilla simples `'` las estabas colocando fuera del `string` de concatenación