# ¿Dónde incluir la ruta de la imagen en php?

Tags: php, html

Esoy intentando hacer que se vea una imagen al lado del nombre de directorio meidante php. (Explicado con más detalle en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/332694/c%C3%B3mo-poner-una-imagen-a-un-directorio/332708#332708))

He conseguido que no me salga ningún error, aunque tampoco he hecho un avance como tal. No sé si estoy yendo bien hacia mi objetivo, o si he vuelto al inicio.

Este es mi código actual:

```
$nombre_directorio = $name;

            $url_imagen = '';

                switch($nombre_directorio) {

                case 'perro':
                echo '<img src="' .$url_imagen. '">'; break;

                case "gato": 
                echo '<img src="' .$url_imagen. '">'; break;

                case 'conejo':
                echo '<img src="' .$url_imagen. '">'; break;

        }

    // Output
     echo("
        <tr class='$class'>
            <td><a href='./$namehref' class='imagen_directorio'>$name</a></td>
            <td><a href='./$namehref'>$extn</a></td>
            <td sorttable_customkey='$sizekey'><a href='./$namehref'>$size</a></td>
            <td sorttable_customkey='$timekey'><a href='./$namehref'>$modtime</a></td>
        </tr>");
```

En el que por web, no se ve ninguna imagen, claramente porque no tiene ninguna ruta a la que dirigirse.

Y ahí va mi pregunta. ¿Cómo puedo definir la ruta para que lo consulte según el nombre que tenga el fichero?

Teniendo en cuenta que sé prácticamente nada de PHP, esto se me va bastante, pero lo intento. He leído sobre lo que quiero hacer [aquí](https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=553:switch-php-case-break-default-condicional-irangos-o-intervalos-ejemplos-ejercicios-resueltos-cu00820b&catid=70&Itemid=193) y [aquí](https://www.anerbarrena.com/php-switch-3430/), también en [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_switch.asp), incluso en el manual de PHP (el cual no me sirvió de nada porque no entendí nada). Pero aún así no consigo lo que busco.

Veo que tiene un `default`, pero no sé hasta dónde esto es necesario, si sirve de algo o sencillamente qué habría que poner.

Estoy actualmente muy perdida. No sé si voy bien, o mal, y tampoco se cómo seguir. Por más que leo, encuentro lo mismo, con el mismo código y con el mismo resultado, pero no lo que busco.

## ACTUALIZACIÓN

Edité el código de esta manera:

```
$nombre_directorio = $name;

            $url_imagen = '';

            switch($nombre_directorio) {
            case 'prueba1':
            $url_imagen = './perro.jpg';
            break;
            case 'prueba2':
            $url_imagen = './gato.jpg';
            break;
            case 'prueba3':
            $url_imagen = './conejo.jpg';
            break;
            }

            echo '<img src="' . $url_imagen . '">';



    // Output
     echo("
        <tr class='$class'>
            <td><a href='./$namehref' class='imagen_directorio'>$name</a></td>
            <td><a href='./$namehref'>$extn</a></td>
            <td sorttable_customkey='$sizekey'><a href='./$namehref'>$size</a></td>
            <td sorttable_customkey='$timekey'><a href='./$namehref'>$modtime</a></td>
        </tr>");
```

Pero al entrar en la ruta me sale este error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$url_imagen' (T_VARIABLE) in
>   /var/www/html/docext/prueba/.index.php on line 122

La línea 122 es:

```
$url_imagen = './perro.jpg';
```

No sé cómo debería poder verse cada imagen con su respectivo nombre, no lo consigo de ninguna forma

Comment: Perdón, habia publicado un comentario pero no había leído la interacción en el chat que tuviste. En el ejemplo del chat que te dieron fue bastante claro al respecto. Si solo van a ser unas pocas imagenes que sabes que corresponden a un determinado nombre, podes definir ahi mismo dentro del switch, la ruta a la imagen correspondiente a cada caso. Cito el mismo código de phpMyGuel

Comment: [Link al código del chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53656269#53656269)

Con respecto al default, no es obligatorio pero si seria mejor que tuvieras una imagen predefinida cuando no se den ninguno de los casos particulares (perro, gato, etc)

Comment: Lo que ocurre es que, cuando pongo la ruta, tampoco me sale nada. Hay algo que me estoy saltando que es la parte en la que tiene que salir en la web, que no sé cómo hacerlo. Voy a editar la pregunta con lo que edité

Comment: Si te fijas en [Este link](https://www.anerbarrena.com/php-switch-3430/) que pusiste al inicio, la sentencia "case" lleva dos puntos. Entonces deberias poner:
`case 'prueba2': $url_imagen = './perro.jpg'; break;`

Cuando actualizaste el código se te pasaron.

Comment: Con eso ya no deberías tener un error de sintaxis. Si las imágenes están donde corresponden, deberían de poder verse.

Comment: ¡Sí! Ahora solo me falta arreglar el css. Gracias por las aclaraciones ^^, estaba líadisima ya de intentar tantas cosas

Comment: Puede que esté entrando a un `case` que no sean los que has listado, prueba con poner al final del `case ` un `default: $url_imagen = './perro.jpg';`

Comment: De nada, cualquier otra pregunta podes hacer una nueva o responde este comentario y lo intentamos solucionar. Un gusto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con ayuda de @phpMyGuel y @Franco Schillage logré dar con la solución.

Primero hice una lista en donde el `case` tiene que ser igual al nombre del archivo, junto con la ruta de la imagen que aparecerá a su lado.

```
    $nombre_directorio = $name;

    $url_imagen = '';

    switch($nombre_directorio) {

    case 'prueba1':
    $url_imagen = './.prueba2.jpg'; break;

    case 'prueba2':
    $url_imagen = './.prueba2.jpg'; break;

    case 'prueba3':
    $url_imagen = './.prueba3.jpg'; break;
    }
```

Luego, llamando a lo que se mostrará en pantalla con un echo, invocas a que el código aparezca en la parte del nombre que indica el directorio existente.

```
// Output
 echo("
    <tr class='$class'>
        <td><img src='" .$url_imagen. "'><a href='./$namehref' class='imagen_directorio'>$name</a></td>
        <td><a href='./$namehref'>$extn</a></td>
        <td sorttable_customkey='$sizekey'><a href='./$namehref'>$size</a></td>
        <td sorttable_customkey='$timekey'><a href='./$namehref'>$modtime</a></td>
    </tr>");
   }
}
```